ADF mapping por posicion de columnas
En Synapse estoy desarrollando una pipeline para cargar diversos archivos csv desde blob storage a su respectiva tabla sql en un pool sql dedicado
Por la naturaleza de los archivos de origen necesito hacer el mapeo de columnas mediante la posicion de la columna
para esto genere para cada tabla un archivo con el esquema correspondiente que mapea la posición de la columna en el origen, con el nombre de la columnas de destino
{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[
{"source":{"ordinal":1},"sink":{"name":"col_a"}},
{"source":{"ordinal":2},"sink":{"name":"col_b"}},
{"source":{"ordinal":3},"sink":{"name":"col_c"}},
{"source":{"ordinal":4},"sink":{"name":"col_d"}}]}

El origen esta configurado para que considere la primera fila como encabezados
El gran problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto la pipeline, el copy activity pareciera estar esperando que las columnas en el archivo se llamen "Prop_#", ya que me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:
'{"Prop_0":"col_a","Prop_1":"col_b","Prop_2":"col_c","Prop_3":"col_d".... Detailed message: Column 'Prop_0' defined in column mapping cannot be found in Source structure
Como puedo configurarlo para que funcione como deberia?
Intento generar una pipeline con un copyactivity, mapeando la columna del origen en base a su posición
